# add class to img tag in specific div

Tags: jquery, css

Here is my sample div:

```
<div id="question-display">
    <img src="/assets/img/sample.png" /> //Line 1
    <img src="/assets/img/sample.png" /> //Line 2
    <img src="/assets/img/sample.png" /> //Line 3
</div>
```

How I can use jquery such as:

```
$('img').addClass('img-responsive');
```

and add class `img-responsive` to img tag in div `id="question-display"`

My expected output after use jquery:

```
<div id="question-display">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="/assets/img/sample.png" />  //Line 1
    <img class="img-responsive" src="/assets/img/sample1.png" /> //Line 2
    <img class="img-responsive" src="/assets/img/sample2.png" /> //Line 3
</div>
```

Comment: Do you see the class being added on the img in browser web inspector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get img inside element with id 'question-display'

```
$('#question-display img').addClass('img-responsive');
```

Answer (score 0):

Select `img` descendants by putting a space

```
$('#question-display img').addClass('img-responsive');
```

If you wish to target direct descendants, then use a `>`

```
$('#question-display > img').addClass('img-responsive');
```

```js
$('#question-display img').addClass('img-responsive');
```

```css
.img-responsive{
  border:1px solid green;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="question-display">
    <img src="/assets/img/sample.png" /> 
    <img src="/assets/img/sample.png" /> 
    <img src="/assets/img/sample.png" /> 
</div>
```